# Why is my right margin overlapping onto the left margin in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, margin

Everything works fine in FF, or safari, but IE is creating overlapping problems with my margins and I can't figure out how to fix the css to account for it.  I've tried to use a css reset file and it actually makes things worse.  Is there anything I can alter in my original CSS to fix the problem?

[Website page](http://www.bodegacooperativacigales.com)

[CSS Stylesheet](http://www.bodegacooperativacigales.com/style.css)

Comment: The question is not clear. The site changed and the css is gone.

Answer (score 0):

u will want to put a browser check in that says if the browser is ie use a different css file.   This works if you have quite a few things you need to change.  You can use these conditional comments for inline css as well.

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/StandardsCompliant.css" />
<!--[endif]-->
<!--[if IE]> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ie.css" /> 
<![endif]-->
```

check out this link for more info 
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply Brian.  This seems like a good idea, but I don't really know how to make a stylesheet specific to IE.

Comment: There isn't really a trick to it. you just make the styles so they display correctly in ie by trial and error and when it is correct save the file then reference it in the link as shown.   Without seeing the code you can try putting a margin-right on the left element and use this to position things for IE.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it's difficult to understand exactly what happens. It might be due to margin collapse (see http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/ ), due to IE margin bugs or some other reason.

Easiest fix for IE is to make specific stylesheets for IE with conditional comments. 
Eg.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

This is a clean solution also in the sense that performance hit is only on the browser with the problems, and main stylesheet doesn't get excessively complex.

Read more about conditional comments from http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Another common strategy for targetting a specific browser is to use JS to detect the browser, attach a relevant class to html or body-elements in DOM (for ex. class called ie7, ie8, chrome11, ...) and then use that in the css like this:

```
.button {width: 100px; padding: 10px;}
.ie7 .button {width: 120px; padding: 10px;}
```

This enables writing simple fixes for browser versions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I don't really know how to make a stylesheet  precisely for IE. I merely modified the current css stylesheet I am working with. Is there an easy tutorial somewhere that I can try to follow that deals specifically with css for IE?

Comment: For example, I imagine that one of my issues is the tag:              }
#pichead{
 margin-left:170px;
 margin-top:70px;                                                 What would I need to change in the css for IE?  Change the hash sign or change the margin to an absolute?

Comment: there's an explanation in quirksmode on the page I linked. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html - I added some further methods to my answer.